# Pydantic - pass JSON_OPTIONS to custom encoder

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

Say we have a Pydantic object that we want to insert into MongoDB:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from datetime import datetime

class A(pydantic.BaseModel):
    w: ObjectId
    x: datetime
```

The built-in `BaseModel.json` method does not handle BSON documents, so I need to pass a custom encoder:

```
from bson import json_util

a = A(w=ObjectId("123"), x=datetime(2023,1,1))
a.json(encoder=json_util.dumps, exclude_none=True)
```

Because of default behavior for `json_util.dumps`, above results in a very ugly BSON where dates are shown as *either* a dictionary (`{"$date": "2023-01-01"}`) or a timestamp (`{"$date": {"$numberLong": "12314215"}}`).

Found [this documentation on `json_util`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html#bson.json_util.DatetimeRepresentation.ISO8601), and I tried to pass in `json_options` to `pydantic.BaseModel.json`... but it does not work.

```
TypeError: JSONEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json_options'
```

But I just passed in a custom encoder... The kwarg should be passed to `json_util.dumps`, but clearly that is not the case here.

Alternatively, I could convert the whole thing to just a string. But I wanted to properly encode my document before insert into MongoDB. I don't want my ObjectId to be converted to a string.

The data serializes just fine, but looking at these date values in Mongo is just uncomfortable.

This should not be this difficult... What am I missing?

Alternatively, I could convert the whole thing to just a string. But I wanted to properly encode my document before insert into MongoDB. I don't want my ObjectId to be converted to a string.

The data serializes just fine, but looking at these date values in Mongo is just uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pydantic's `dict()` method](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) to convert your model into a dictionary, then insert that into MongoDB:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from datetime import datetime
import pydantic
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['test']

class A(pydantic.BaseModel):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

    w: ObjectId
    x: datetime

a = A(w=ObjectId(), x=datetime(2023, 1, 1))

db['mycollection'].insert_one(a.dict())
```

mongosh:

```
test> db.mycollection.findOne()
{
  _id: ObjectId("649627207cac51eab98924cb"),
  w: ObjectId("649627207cac51eab98924ca"),
  x: ISODate("2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```